# in case of TreeMap , if pass our own class object as key then which interface is needed to be implemented Comparable or Comparator and why?

Tags: java, collections, treemap

In case of "TreeMap" , if pass our own class object as key then which interface is needed to be implemented Comparable or Comparator and why?

Comment: Well, did you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you construct the `TreeMap` specifying a comparator, then that will be used to compare the keys.

If you construct the `TreeMap` *without* specifying a comparator, then the keys must implement `Comparable`.

Typically the key would implement `Comparable` if there's a natural ordering, but you'd use a separate class as a `Comparator` for some custom ordering, or if there *is* no natural ordering for the key type. It would be unusual for the key type to implement `Comparator` itself.

Comment: so when to use Comparable and when Comparator?   can u give me any example?

Comment: @SumitPatyal: I've already explained in the answer: if the key has a *natural* ordering (as numbers do, for example) then it makes sense for them to implement `Comparable`. If you need a more *custom* ordering (e.g. to order a `Person` collection by name, or by age) then use a `Comparator`.